# Datafile transfer between two folder with certain condition

Tags: java, spring, file, ftp

My Requirement:
I have 2 folders. Folder one has 4 files(3 csv and Info file).
The second folder is place where FTP happens.
Requirement is transfer the csv files first to second folder.
Once FTP is completed for these folder then transfer the info file to second folder.

In a day there will be millions set of file going to be placed in first folder.
I can't use Thread.sleep() to wait until the csv's are picked not to transfer the info file.

How to achieve this in java?

Comment: What do you mean by "FTP happens"? What makes the FTP happen? Why must the info file be transfered last? Can't you just filter the files to be transfered via FTP?

Comment: 2 nd folder  a place where Pollers picks and start FTP process to downstream system. Its a different application we can't change logic there.